# How to change the x-axis scale on the histogram in base r

Tags: r, histogram, scale

I have a histogram that has an x-scale showing 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.
How do I change it so it only shows 0, 2, 4, 6 ?
In base r please.

Comment: Uh... the data is here. 
https://github.com/rdpeng/ExData_Plotting1

Comment: can you share the code that you have tried which gives you histogram that has an x-scale showing 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me as expected without specifying `xlim`

```
hist(exdata1$Global_active_power, main = "Global Active Power", 
      xlab = "Global Active Power (kilowatts)", col = "red")
```

[image]